# Regex in C# and WPF to Validate Various Input type

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, validation

I would like to ask how to properly validate an input in C#. I'm creating a desktop app.

I've been doing some issue when validating some input in the text box. Currently I'm working on the email field but no luck. I've tested my `regex` and it seems to work fine but as I tried to place it and run my code the validation run as soon as I hit the first key.

I want to ask if its possible to trigger the validation on tab or enter so the regex will validate the whole string I input

See my code Snipet below:

```
private void Eid_txt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string strEid = (sender as TextBox).Text;

    if (!Regex.IsMatch(strEid, @"^((([\w]+\.[\w]+)+)|([\w]+))@(([\w]+\.)+)([A-Za-z]{1,3})$"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please input valid email address ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to validate the complete string once user exit the field. So change the event instead of validating on TextChanged you should validate on LostFocus event

Comment: I'd go for the "correct" route and use the validation mechanisms in the bindings. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextChanged` event will be fired, as the name suggests, whenever the text in the text box changes (usually as you type in). This means that your regex will be applied at each key stroke, thus causing it to fail each time (unless the user pastes the email at once).

You probably have a  `Submit`, `Edit`, `Save` or some other button which when pressed would update the data. In this method, you would then include your testing mechanism.

Alternatively, you could make use of the [`Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.lostkeyboardfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

> Occurs when an element loses keyboard focus.

This should allow you to make your validation once that your text box looses focus, which would assume that the user has finished keying in his/her details for that particular text box.

As per your comment:

```
private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (TxtBxValidation()) 
        return; 

    WorkerDetailsxxxx xxxx = new WorkerDetailsxxxx(); 
    xxxx.id = this.Team_ID.Text; 
    xxxx.Name = this.Name_txt.Text; 
    xxxx.Email = this.Eid_txt.Text; 
    xxxx.Address = this.Address_txt.Text; 
    xxxx.Age= this.age_txt.Text; 
    WorkerConnection.saveWorker(xxxx); 

    Worker_List.ItemsSource = null; 
    Worker_List.ItemsSource = WorkerConnection.GetAllList(); 
    ClearForm(); 
    MessageBox.Show("Worker successfully saved."); 
}
```

You could amend `TxtBxValidation()`:

```
public bool TxtBxValidation()
{
    ...

    string strEid = <textBox>.Text;
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(strEid, @"^((([\w]+\.[\w]+)+)|([\w]+))@(([\w]+\.)+)([A-Za-z]{1,3})$"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please input valid email address ");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have those button:
heres my add button.how can i integrate the regex validation to this.
`private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
if (TxtBxValidation())
return;
WorkerDetailsxxxx xxxx = new WorkerDetailsxxxx();
xxxx.id = this.Team_ID.Text;
xxxx.Name = this.Name_txt.Text;
xxxx.Email = this.Eid_txt.Text;
xxxx.Address = this.Address_txt.Text;
xxxx.Age= this.age_txt.Text;
WorkerConnection.saveWorker(xxxx);
Worker_List.ItemsSource = null;
Worker_List.ItemsSource =WorkerConnection.GetAllList();
ClearForm();    
MessageBox.Show("Worker successfully saved.");          
}`

Comment: i TRIED what u suggest but the sender (sender as TextBox) show error :sender name doesnt exist in current context

`public Boolean TxtBxValidation()
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eid_txt.Text.Trim()))
{MessageBox.Show("Email Field is Empty!");
return true;}
string strEid = (sender as TextBox).Text;
if (!Regex.IsMatch(strEid, @"^((([\w]+\.[\w]+)+)|([\w]+))@(([\w]+\.)+)([A-Za-z]{1,3})$"))
{
MessageBox.Show("Please input valid email address ");
return false;
}
return false;
}
`

Comment: @Jigen: Sorry my mistake. I have amended the code. <textBox> is the name of the text box you want to validate, I presume you want to match `Eid_txt`.

Comment: Sorry my bad i will just recheck it i havent try directly validating the txtbox

Comment: @Jigen: As a side note, your method name is slightly confusing. `TxtBoxValidation()` would ideally return `true` if no errors, `false` if otherwise. Altenatively , you could rename the method to `FormContainsErrors()`.